# Как правильно сверстать секцию

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как правильно сверстать данную секцию.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Схему вырезал картинкой, ставлю ее бекграундом и под нее выравниваю текст, но естественно при изменении размеров экрана все это уезжает(

Comment: Первое что надо понять, это как она должна масштабироваться на разных разерах экрана, например как это будет выглядеть на мобильном. Какие части будут сохранять размер, а какие должны растягиваться.

Comment: Первое что приходит это оранжевую часть оставить картинкой, так как там кривые линии и как верстать не очень понятно, а вот левую сделать адаптивной. На большинстве экранов будет выглядеть нормально, но вопрос остаётся с мобильными телефонами. Так же для адекватного масштабирования оранжевую картинку можно сделать на `SVG`.

Comment: думаю для мобильных надо отдельно делать. А для больших экранов строки слева делать `div`ами с фиксированной высотой, а картинку жёстко закрепить.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин ну для больших экранов приблизительно так и сделал, а вот дальше что-то совсем теряюсь как это состыковать можно, думаю уже сделать только заголовок а остальное картинкой, но не хотелось бы конечно(

Comment: Так для больших экранов разобрались? Думаю для мобильника просто надо отдельно рисовать схему, или надписи которые тут слева прямо поверху цветных закидывать. Либо вниз пирамиды. А состыкуется это через Media Queris. Это специальная функциональность css позволяющая делать разные стили для разных размеров экрана.